# Make Facebook permission window modal

Tags: javascript, facebook, modal-dialog

I'm using the standard code from Facebook JS SDK in order to get the permissions for an application (this is an example with email permission):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (!response.authResponse) {
        //user refused to grant permissions, redirect to the 'index' page
        window.location = "/";
    }
}, {scope:"email"});
```

When the user tries to get into the application's page (the function above is on page load), the permission request window pops-up, but it can be moved or even put in icon, while the user can still view the page. Is there any mean that I can assign the permission request window as a modal one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user to login using the `getLoginUrl()` function in the PHP SDK. This redirects the user to a complete Facebook Login page and then have it redirect back to your app once complete.

E.g. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}`

Comment: Yes, that's it, we need to use the PHP SDK rather than JavaScript.